# Definition of surface gravity via the non-affine geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, geodesics

I have found a discrepancy in the way different sources define surface gravity (or derive) via the non-affine geodesic equation satisfied by the a Killing vector $\xi$ on a Killing Horizon (KH), up to a sign. That is, on the one hand Ref. 1, Ref.2, Ref. 3 (and many others) claim that on the KH
$$\xi^{\mu}\xi_{\nu;\mu}=\kappa\xi_\nu,\tag{1a}\label{1a}$$
while Ref. 4, Ref. 5 claim that on the KH
$$\xi^{\mu}\xi_{\nu;\mu}=-\kappa\xi_\nu.\tag{1b}\label{1b}$$

As harmless as it may seem, I don't believe this is just convention, as in that case different authors should get answers differing by a sign but all of the quoted references agree that e.g. for the Schwarzschild BH, $\kappa=1/4M$, **not** $k=\pm1/4M$, the upper sign referring to \eqref{1a} and the lower sign to \eqref{1b}.

Furthermore, upon affine reparametrizazion of geodesics along e.g. the future Schwarzschild horizon (parametrized by $u=t-r^\ast$), since $\kappa$ is constant one gets in the two cases that the affine parameter $\lambda$ is
$$\lambda\propto e^{\pm u}$$
where again the sign is according to \eqref{1a} and \eqref{1b}; in the second case this means that $\lambda\propto U$, where $U$ is a Kruskal null coordinate, but the same is not true in the first case (or possibly not in the same Kruskal patch?).
What is the subtetly going on here?

---

### References

1. *A relativist's toolkit. The Mathematics of black hole mechanics*, E. Poisson. CUP, 2008. Eq. $(5.40)-(5.41)$;
2. *General Relativity*, R. M. Wald. University of Chicago Press, 1984. Eq. $(12.5.2)-(12.5.5)$;
3. [Townsend's review of BH](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707012), eq. $(2.82)$;
4. *Spacetime and geometry*, S. Carroll. CUP, 2019. Eq. $(6.8)$
5. *Particle creation by Black Holes*, SWH. Just after Eq. $(2.16)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the Carroll book in front of me, but in Hawking's paper he was describing in the paragraph above (2.16) that $\lambda$ was a parameter on the past horizon of the global Schwarzschild spacetime.  On the past horizon, the surface gravity is defined as $\xi^a\nabla_a \xi^b = - \kappa \xi^b$, and with this definition $\kappa$ is positive.  This equation is saying that $\xi^a$ is getting shorter as you move up the past horizon toward the bifurcation surface.  The analogous equation on the future horizon is $\xi^a\nabla_a \xi^b = \kappa \xi^b$, with the same (positive) value of $\kappa$.

Comment: I was just thinking it might be about past/future horizons (mentioned that in the chat). I checked the lecture notes on which the book is based and unfortunately that part is missing, so I can't provide Carroll's paragraph here. It's possible that it's an error as well, since that equation is never used again and $\kappa=1/4M$ is derived by using the formula for $\kappa^2$, which is clearly the same. Then, I wonder: do you think that most books use the second one without mentioning anything because in typical applications one deals with future horizons?

Comment: OT: Incidentally, do you happen to know anyone following Hawking's derivation but possibly less obscure?